# Как найти сумму всех четных элементов ряда Фибоначчи, которые не превышают четыре миллиона?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, математика, числа-фибоначчи

имеется код который выводит все числа Фибоначчи до 4,000,000. Как посчитать сумму четных чисел?

```
a = 0
b = 1

sum = 0

while b < 4000000:
    print(a, end=" ")
    sum = a + b
    b = a 
    a = sum
```

Comment: Добавить переменную для накопления суммы, проверять каждое очередное число, и по факту чётности плюсить...

Comment: а как проверить число на четность ?

Comment: Вы же знаете, какие числа являются четными? Вот так и проверять. PS. Надо до 4 млн, а вы считаете до трех.

Comment: Таки непонятно - вам нужно выводить только числа или их сумму? А то у вас заголовок вопроса не соответствует его тексту...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен! спасибо за наводку @akina

```
a = 0
b = 1

sum = 0
sum_even = 0

while b < 4000000:
    sum = a + b
    b = a 
    a = sum
    if a % 2 == 0:
        sum_even += a
print(sum_even)
```

Answer (score 6):

Если посмотреть на ряд Фибоначчи и увидеть, что четно каждое третье число, то...

```
n = 0
m = 2
while m < 4000000:
    print(m);
    x = m
    m = m*4 + n
    n = x
```

Ах, да! у вас вроде как в заголовке нужна **сумма** (чего нет в тексте вопроса) - тогда так:

```
n = 0
m = 2
s = 0
while m < 4000000:
    print(m);
    s = s + m
    x = m
    m = m*4 + n
    n = x

print("Sum = ",s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
a = 0
b = 1

sum = 0
sumeven = 0

while b < 300:
    print(a, end=" ")
    if not a&1:
        sumeven+=a
    sum = a + b
    b = a 
    a = sum

print("\n",sumeven)

#0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 
# 188
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось так:

```
a, b = 1, 2
count = 0
while a < 4000000:
    if a % 2 == 0:
        count += a
    a, b = b, a+b
print(count)
```

Comment: Так то хорошо, но почему сумматор называется `count`? Так обычно счётчик называют. Более логично назвать сумматор `summ` или `sum_` (`sum` не желательно, как в других ответах - это перекроет встроенную функцию питона). И ещё отступов многовато у вас, столько не нужно, достаточно 4.

Answer (score 0):

Генератор `fibs` порождает числа Фибоначчи. Не удивляйтесь, он никогда не останавливается, для Питона это нормально.

Генератор `below(g, n)` останавливается как только генератор `g` выдаст значение больше либо равное `n`.

Генератор `evens(g)` пропускает только чётные значения из генератора `g`.

Генератор `even_fibs_below(n)` из всех чисел Фибоначчи порождает небольшие чётные.

```
import itertools


def fibs():
    a, b = 0, 1
    yield a
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b


def below(g, n):
    return itertools.takewhile(lambda v: v < n, g)


def evens(g):
    return filter(lambda v: v % 2 == 0, g)


def even_fibs_below(n):
    return evens(below(fibs(), n))


print(sum(even_fibs_below(4000000)))
```

> ```
> $ python even_fib_sum.py
> 4613732
> ```